# While trying to install lighttpd on debian squeeze I get: 'Some packages could not be installed.'

Tags: debian, packages, debian-squeeze, dependencies, lighttpd

I am trying to install lighttpd on my (virtual) Debian 6.0.4 64 bit system but after trying to use this command :

`sudo apt-get install lighttpd`

I get this error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lighttpd : Depends: libterm-readline-perl-perl but it is not installable
            Recommends: spawn-fcgi but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

Anyone encountered the this problem already ? Any solutions ?

Comment: Are you using only the offical repositories?  Have you ran apt-get update recently?

Comment: @Zoredache I have ran `apt-get update` but nothing is updated. Should I add something to `sources.list` manually ? After installation I have only [this in my `sources.list`](http://pastebin.com/Ma7WSCV8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have figured this out.

I had to manually add repositories to `sources.list`

For instnace : 
`deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian squeeze main`

and manually install `libterm-readline-perl-perl` with the use of `wget` and `dpkg`

This is [the link](http://packages.debian.org/pl/squeeze/all/libterm-readline-perl-perl/download) where you can download `libterm-readline-perl-perl`